# Are my modules incorrectly referenced in this package?

Tags: python

I'd like some help understanding why I get a below error when I run `animals.py` from a Windows command prompt.

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Mammals'

First off: I am new to Python.  I am running version 3.7.4 on Windows 10.  I'm trying to learn how to creat packages by following the the example published on https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-create-a-python-package/.  Here is the minimal code needed to reproduce my problem (note: I indicate which file the code belongs in by placing the filename above it in comments).

```py
################################################
# animals.py
################################################
from Animals import Mammal

mam = Mammal()
mam.printMembers()

################################################
# Animals\__init__.py
################################################
from Mammals import Mammal

################################################
# Animals\Mammals.py
################################################
class Mammal:
   def __init__(self):
      self.members = ['Tiger','Lion']

   def printMembers():
      for a in self.members
         print(a)
```

From a windows command prompt, I execute `python animals.py` and expect to see "Tiger" and "Lion" get printed to the screen.  What I actually get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "animals.py", line 4, in <module>
      from Animals import Mammal
   File "C:\mypy\Animals\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
      from Mammals import Mammal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Mammals'
```

Comment: `Mammal` is a module inside the `Animals` package, so you'd want to use `from .Mammals import Mammal` (note the dot!) or `from Animals.Mammals import Mammal` in the `__init__.py`.

Comment: `from Mammals ...` looks for a *top-level* name to import from, and you don't have such a name.

Comment: Thanks, Martijn.  By 'top level' does that mean from the same directory as where animals.py is located?

Comment: Top level is anything in a directory listed on `sys.path`; that includes the files in the same directory of your starting script `animals.py`, but also the Python.standard library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is within your `__init__.py` file. Syntax should be:

```
from packagename.Filename import Classname
```

so

```
from Animals.Mammals import Mammals
```

should do the trick for you.

btw. do not forget the `self` parameter in your method definitions, e.g.

```
def printMembers(self):
```